# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo'

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

Following error occurs when following Neo4j online training for Data Science.

```
 ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-3-993ba54a3148> in <module>()
          1 from py2neo import Graph
          2 import pandas as pd
          3 import matplotlib
          4 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
          5 

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'py2neo'
```

Answer (score 1):

you probably skipped the first notebook:

```
!pip install py2neo==4.1.3 pandas matplotlib sklearn
```

should help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
pip install py2neo
```

This worked for me

Comment: Please explain why your answer works